# Snowflake - Error Configuring Amazon SNS to Automate Snowpipe Using SQS Notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I followed this tutorial in the snowflake documentation (Option 2) and I have a couple of questions I am hoping someone can help me with.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#option-2-configuring-amazon-sns-to-automate-snowpipe-using-sqs-notifications

1. When I try to create a pipe with the following command

> ```
> create pipe <pipe> 
>     auto_ingest=true 
>     aws_sns_topic='<sns topic arn>.fifo'
>     as
>     copy into <table>
>     FROM (SELECT $1:"id", $1:"name", $1:"contact", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP_NTZ, $1:"active" FROM @<stage>)
>     FILE_FORMAT = <previously defined form which is json>
> ```

I get this error: `Pipe Notifications bind failure "Invalid parameter: Invalid parameter: Endpoint Reason: Please use FIFO SQS queue (Service: Sns, Status Code: 400, Request ID: <request id>, Extended Request ID: null)"`

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong or guide me on how I can troubleshoot this error? I am new to Snowflake.

2. Another thing I did notice about the tutorial which confused me was in Option 2 - Step 1: Subscribe the Snowflake SQS Queue to the SNS Topic.

This seemed to indicate that you should use the sns topic arn in this command

```
select system$get_aws_sns_iam_policy('<sns_topic_arn>');
```

...but then when they expand on their example then use the bucket arn

```
select system$get_aws_sns_iam_policy('arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:001234567890:s3_mybucket');

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SYSTEM$GET_AWS_SNS_IAM_POLICY('ARN:AWS:SNS:US-WEST-2:001234567890:S3_MYBUCKET')                                                                                                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Sid":"1","Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::123456789001:user/vj4g-a-abcd1234"},"Action":["sns:Subscribe"],"Resource":["arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:001234567890:s3_mybucket"]}]}
```

Which should I use for this step?

Thanks!

Comment: The **aws_sns_topic** should be set to **arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:001234567890:s3_mybucket** and that COPY INTO refers to a stage I assume and not an integration as mentioned in your case **FROM @<integration>)**?

Comment: It does refer to a stage. I will update to correct the typo. Thanks. I will also update the arn and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I figured out the problem, in case someone else runs into the same issue. I was trying to subscribe Snowflake SQS Queue to an FIFO SNS topic. This is not possible. This link explains it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66661769/how-to-subscribe-an-sqs-fifo-queue-to-a-standard-sns-topic

Comment: Also if anyone else is trying to follow the docs above and running into issues, it does appear to be telling you to use the bucket arn instead of the sns topic arn, which didn't make sense to me. This link makes it clearer.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-setup-Snowpipe-with-SNS-configuration